# Java Applet below web folder, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, php, deployment, applet

First I embedded an Applet into a page with the APPLET tag like this:

```
<APPLET code="MyApplet.class" codebase="/" align="baseline"
    width="200" height="200">
    Your browser does not support Java Applets.
</APPLET>
```

The applet class file was in the web root directory in the same folder as the PHP page.

Now I moved the class files off the web to the folder above, and I tried to change the code like this:

```
code = "../MyApplet.class"
```

But that seemed to cause the applet to think the class was called "...MyApplet.class"

So then I changed it back and changed the codebase instead like this:

`code = "MyApplet.class"` and `codebase = "../"`

But that still gives me ClassNotFoundException.

I think applets are client-sided so now I am thinking it is not possible to keep the applet class files off of the public domain because they need to be downloaded to the client?

Can anyone confirm this for me please or if I am mistaken tell me how I can put the relative paths in correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another answer..

> URLs do not support notation like `..`

Of course they do!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

class WhereIsMyGrandParent {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("WhereIsMyGrandParent.java");

        URL url = f.toURI().toURL();

        URL parent = new URL(url, "..");
        System.out.println("grand parent: " + parent);
    }
}
```

---

The real problem is in misunderstanding what those parameters are for and how the values are used/what they mean..

```
code="MyApplet.class" codebase="/"
```

**1)** The code attribute should be the Fully Qualified Name of the class.  So correct examples might be

```
code="MyApplet"
```

..or

```
code="com.our.MyApplet"
```

**2)** A `codebase` of  `/` translates to "the root of the domain".  E.G. an applet at http://our.com/applets/stockapplet/applet.html might form an URL of `/` and that would point to http://our.com/.  Note especially that there is no `..` (parent) to be had from the root of a domain.

---

I do not fully understand the structure of the server in terms of location of

1. applet HTML
2. applet code

Please consider providing either explicit (or relative) URLs for the location of each, or better, a nested list.  E.G.

- `/`

  - `code`

    - `MyApplet.class`
  - `applet`

    - `applet.html`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applet class is downloaded by applet plugin to your web browser using the URL that it constructs as concatenation of your page URL and the code base. Since URLs do not support notation like `..` (it is file path notation) you cannot use it when you are configuring your applet.

Comment: *"URLs do not support notation like `..`"*  Wrong!  I explain why in my answer.